# C execve() parameters [spawn a shell example]

Tags: c, shellcode, execve

I have to fill the parameters for:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

If I execute this program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        char *args[2];
        args[0] = "/bin/sh";
        args[1] = NULL;
        execve(args[0], args, NULL);
}
```

the shell is spawned correctly as expected.

My problem is that the shell is spawned correctly also if I pass a NULL as second parameter like that:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
        char *args[2];
        args[0] = "/bin/sh";
        args[1] = NULL;
        execve(args[0], NULL, NULL);
}
```

So what's the purpose to use the args vector (with the "/bin/sh" + NULL) as second parameter instead of a NULL?

Comment: In this case, you're not passing any arguments, so there is no difference. You could choose to pass some argument within `args`.

Comment: And so, why in all the example I see, people use to pass the /bin/sh + NULL as arg? It's simpler to understand with the arg parameter directly set to NULL.

Comment: It's probably because it's an example to understand that if I pass some parameters, there must be a NULL as string terminator?

Comment: Write yourself a C program which prints out the arguments, you should see a difference if you call it with your two sample programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line: `execve(args[0], NULL, NULL);` you are simply using the first element of `args` array. You could also use something like `char* command="/bin/sh"`. You **have to** pass something, because that's how `execve()` was defined. In your case you pass `NULL` because you don't need to pass anything.

The point of the second argument of `execve()` is to pass arguments to the command you are spawning. Suppose that instead of shell you simply want to execute `ls`, you could then pass f.e. these arguments:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
        char *args[2];
        args[0] = "/bin/ls";
        args[1] = "-lh";
        execve(args[0], args, NULL);
}
```

Also, quoting `man execve`:

> argv is an array of argument strings passed to the new program.  **By
>   convention, the first of these strings should contain the filename
>   associated  with the file being executed**.  envp is an array of
>   strings, conventionally of the form key=value, which are passed as
>   environment to the new program.

Comment: You need `NULL` in the last element of `args`.

Answer (score 5):

If you pass a null pointer as the second, or the third, argument of `execve`, your program is incorrect according to POSIX; both of these arguments are required to be non-null.  (This is not all that clearly stated in [the specification of `execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), but it's in there.)  I am currently typing this on an operating system that treats passing null pointers,

```
execve("executable", 0, 0);
```

as equivalent to passing empty arrays, e.g.

```
execve("executable", (char *[]){0}, (char *[]){0});
```

but it would not surprise me to learn that other operating systems would fire a segmentation fault or return -1 with `errno` set to `EFAULT` or `EINVAL`.

Passing empty arrays for these arguments is allowed, but the newly executed program will receive zero arguments in `argc`/`argv` if the second argument is an empty array, and/or zero environment variables in `envp`/`environ` if the third argument is an empty array.  Many programs will malfunction under these conditions.  For instance, it is very common to see things like

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   if (argc != 4) {
     fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s one two three\n", argv[0]);
     return 2;
   }
   // ...
}
```

where the program implicitly assumes that `argv[0]` will always be non-null.

So, you should always provide *non-empty* arrays for both arguments.  The usual convention is that if you don't have anything else to do, you use

```
execve(program, (char *[]){program, 0}, environ);
```

which supplies the program's own name as `argv[0]` and no further arguments, and the same set of environment variables you got from your own parent.